# SpriteKit Error - when changing font color

Tags: swift, fonts, sprite-kit

Hi I'm using SpriteKit and Swift, I've come across this problem while I was working on this code. I'm trying to have a label below a image on a scene. The Image is working great, but the label isn't displaying. So far theres no errors when I remove "button.fontColor = ..." but it just doesn't appear on the screen. I may have my positioning wrong, or my colors or both.
Heres my Code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image.png")
    logo.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    self.addChild(logo)

    let button = SKLabelNode()
    label.text = "Tap Anywhere to Continue."
    label.position = CGPoint(x:100,y:100)
    label.fontColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    self.addChild(button)
}
```

And while your at it, do you mind helping me making the label's position be right under the center of the scene? I'm not so sure how to do that!

Thanks so much guys, your too kind for helping newbies out!   :) 
    I <3 stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you meant `button` to be `label`. This should work. Hopefully gets you close to what you wanted for positioning too.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let logo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image.png")
        logo.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        self.addChild(logo)


        let padding : CGFloat = 10.0
        //let button = SKLabelNode()
        let label = SKLabelNode()
        label.text = "Tap Anywhere to Continue."
        label.verticalAlignmentMode = .Top
        label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
        label.position = CGPoint(x:logo.position.x,y:logo.position.y-logo.size.height/2-padding)
        label.fontColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        //self.addChild(button)
        self.addChild(label)
    }
}
```